# MongooseDocumentArray assignment

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I have a `MongooseDocumentArray` found at `this.prices`. I can clear it with `this.prices = []` and it retains all of its methods etc. and remains a `MongooseDocumentArray`. If I assign it to another variable first, e.g. `array = this.prices`, then `array` is also a `MongooseDocuementArray`, and changing one changes the other (i.e. they appear to be the same object). However, if I then attempt to clear that one with `array = []`, I find that array is now a plain, empty JS array. Doing `array.length = 0` works fine, however. Can someone explain to me why this is and also how doing it with the original object works? I'm guessing this is more of a JS thing than a specifically Mongoose thing, but either way I'm perplexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first say:

```
this.prices = [];
```

... then mongoose is using what's known as a "setter" to intercept the assignment and cast it into a `MongooseDocumentArray`.  Behind the scenes mongoose does this for all setting of paths on documents, not just document arrays.  It uses `Object.defineProperty` to achieve this.  Read more on that and its capabilities [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

What happens after that is more straightforward. When you then assign that to another variable:

```
array = this.prices;
```

... then you are assigning a reference to the cast `this.prices` object to `array`.

But when you say:

```
array = [];
```

... then you are *changing* that reference, causing `array` to point to a new `Array` object.

`array.length = 0` on the other hand modifies the `DocumentArray`, but leaves the reference intact.

If you dig around in [the source](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose), particularly [document.js](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/master/lib/document.js#L392) and the various `types`, you can begin to figure out how mongoose handles this.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm not really up on how setters actually work. I should probably get on that because at the moment it looks like magic. I'll accept this when it lets me.

Comment: Yep, that post is the gist of it but it's quite dated (2007).  Mongoose uses the more modern `Object.defineProperty`.  I'll link it in the answer.

Comment: Sadly, this is putting a kink in my attempt to stay DRY. I have several separate but related EmbeddedDocumentArrays in my model & which one a method needs to access is indeterminate. I was hoping pass the proper one to a helper method that would operate on whichever one it was passed (clear it and create new entries). While using length = 0 got me closer, it also seems that methods like `create` don't function correctly if called on the reference variable. The docs get created but the schema's validation doesn't appear to work, as I'm getting duplicate records despite unique constraints.

Comment: Are you `push`-ing the created documents to the array some time after creating them?  `create` should make objects, but not actually add them to the doc.  It's hard to determine what your problem is without more code, but it's possible that the way you're adding the new docs isn't flagging the parent as modified, or something...  You should probably open a new question detailing your issue rather before this turns into a comment discussion.

Comment: Yeah. I'm pushing them too. I'll revisit it and if it just wasn't me doing something stupid, I'll post a new question as you suggested.